# Differences between Scorm 2004 3rd and 4th edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

What do I have to change to get my 3rd ed content compatible to 4th ed specifiactions?

Does anyone know an abstract of the changes or do I have to compare the whole cam and rte specifications?

Can't find such a document neither at adlnet.org nor searching globaly.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Mike Rustici puts it well on http://scorm.com/blog/2009/01/scorm-2004-4th-edition/.
It's more sequence and navigation updates which would effect packaging things more than the development or API interactions.

Thanks,
Mark